# How to prettify the json text in the Excel cell?

Tags: json, excel

In the excel file, there are a lot of json texts like below

```json
{"component":"{{$labels.component}}","container":"{{$labels.container}}","daemonset":"{{$labels.daemonset}}","directory":"{{$labels.directory}}","figure":"{{$value}}","instance":"{{$labels.instance}}","job":"{{$labels.job}}","name":"{{$labels.name}}","namespace":"{{$labels.namespace}}","pod":"{{$labels.pod}}","reason":"{{$labels.reason}}"}
```

I want to prettify the json text like this

```json
{
 "component": "{{$labels.component}}",
 "container": "{{$labels.container}}",
 "daemonset": "{{$labels.daemonset}}",
 "directory": "{{$labels.directory}}",
 "figure": "{{$value}}",
 "instance": "{{$labels.instance}}",
 "job": "{{$labels.job}}",
 "name": "{{$labels.name}}",
 "namespace": "{{$labels.namespace}}",
 "pod": "{{$labels.pod}}",
 "reason": "{{$labels.reason}}"
}
```

Is there any way to do this for any cells in my excel file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 current channel then you can use this formula - where your json is in cell `A1`

```vb
=LET(json,A1,
     r,SUBSTITUTE(json,",","," & CHAR(10)),
    "{" & CHAR(10) & MID(r,3,LEN( r)-3) & CHAR(10) & "}")
```

First it replaces the comma by a comma plus a linebreak char(10). Then it handles the first and last linebreak.